# How to compile protocol buffer service to scala code?

Tags: scala, hbase, protocol-buffers

I am building an API service using Play Framework in Scala and I am using HBase as my database. I want to use HBase coprocessors and since my HBase version is 1.0.0 I have to implement my service to be compatible with Protocol Buffer. I am following cloudera documentation for endpoint coprocessor. I need to create a proto file and then use a protocol buffer compiler to generate the service interface that needs to be implemented by client. I could not find any Scala protocol buffer compiler that can generate scala code from a proto file that has **service**(not only messages). [here](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/hbase-coprocessors#(endpoints-coprocessor)) you can see an example of a proto file with service that is used for a coprocessor. What can I do?

Comment: Use Java then interop in Scala

Comment: That's right. I was trying to avoid patches, but anyways this will indeed solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is Scala implementation for `protobuf`. Google `scalabuff`.

Comment: That does not work for services. check out the documentation: https://github.com/SandroGrzicic/ScalaBuff/wiki/Generated-code#user-content-services